# Enable CORS for EC2 .JSON file

Tags: json, nginx, amazon-ec2, cors, observablehq

I have a little knowledge of backend but posted some documents on a EC2 Amazon Linux AMI instance served with nginx.

I am trying to access a .json file posted in /var/www/html from Observablehq, but i get the following error when I try to fetch that url:

> Access to fetch at 'https://herdtrails.com/data.json' from origin
>   'https://askbid.static.observableusercontent.com' has been blocked by
>   CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
>   request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I am not sure how and where I should enable CORS, do I have to add anything to nginx.conf, or maybe I have to create a node.js app to serve with CORS?

As I said I am learning right now about backend so I am quite lost.

Answer (score 1):

You should add CORS headers to the response to let the browser accept it.
See [how to add cors headers to nginx](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

It would be better if you'll use `https://askbid.static.observableusercontent.com` instead of `*`

I highly recommend to read some basic info on CORS to better understand what you're actually doing.